# Looking to return a list of IDs after an underscore filter

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

I'm wondering if there's an easy way to return a list of IDs from a filtered array.

Here's a JSFiddle where I'm filtering an array http://jsfiddle.net/eRzBL/

```
var array = [{'id':1, 'Color':'blue'},
             {'id':2, 'Color':'orange'}, 
             {'id':3, 'Color':'green'}, 
             {'id':4, 'Color':'blue'} ];

var myFilter = array.filter(function (item) {
                    return item.Color === 'blue';
                });
```

Instead of returning a list of objects, I'd like to return a list of IDs.  In this case [1,4].  I could create a new array, loop over this collection and append the IDs but I was wondering if I could do this using existing underscore functionality.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can extend the idea by passing the filtered data to `map` to get only the ids.

```
var result = array.filter(function(item) {
    return item.Color === 'blue';
}).map(function(item) {
    return item.id;
});

console.log(result)
# [1, 4]
```

If you want to do this with underscore,

```
var result = _.chain(array)
    .filter(function(item) {
        return item.Color === 'blue';
    })
    .pluck("id")
    .value();

console.log(result);
# [1, 4]
```

Also, you can make use of [`_.where`](http://underscorejs.org/#where), like this

```
var result = _.chain(array)
    .where({Color: 'blue'})
    .pluck("id")
    .value();

console.log(result)
# [1, 4]
```

If you prefer oneliners,

```
console.log(_.pluck(_.where(array, {Color: 'blue'}), "id"));
# [1, 4]
```

**Note:** None of the above seen methods can beat the native JavaScript's performance

```
var result = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i].Color === "blue") {
        result.push(array[i].id);
    }
}
console.log(result);
# [1, 4]
```